# How to set icon to kivy application in taskbar?

Tags: python, windows, icons, kivy, taskbar

I have a kivy application in which i want to set a certain icon. I have managed to place the icon to the kivy window with this code:

```
        Window.set_icon('logo.jpg')
        Config.set('kivy', 'window_icon', 'logo.jpg')
```

But how can I change the taskbar icon for this certain kivy application?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `self.icon = "logo.jpg"` in your `App`'s `build` method..

Comment: That is not updating the taskbar's icon, only the window's icon.

Comment: @moro_922 Did you tried to un-pin it and then pin it again?